# Getting trackback spam, even with trackbacks disabled

Tags: spam, configuration

I'm having a heck of a time having trackbacks being disabled period on my self-hosted blog. I've disabled the "Allow link notifications from other blogs (pingbacks and trackbacks)" option, and have all comments going through disqus, yet for some reason I'm getting 20-50 trackbacks a day to the blog directly (not through disqus). Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you also disabled XMLRPC?  Check the source of your page for the <link rel="pingback" href="..." />` element as well.

Comment: I have not. I thought there would be a way to do so but there doesnt' seem to be in the admin panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a twentyten/eleven theme, they hardcode the pingback meta tag into the `head.php` file. Remove that line or use your own theme. Also, and maybe it's only in multisite, but the X-Pingback header is sent along with the xmlrpc endpoint url as well. Removed with the following:

```
/**
 * Remove the X-Pingback header, since pingbacks are disabled
 */
add_filter('wp_headers', 'custom_remove_xmlrpc_header', 1, 2);
function custom_remove_xmlrpc_header($headers, $wp_object){
  if (array_key_exists('X-Pingback', $headers))
    unset($headers['X-Pingback']);
  return $headers;
 }
```

Comment: I'm using the mystique theme, but it had the line you specified hardcoded. Will give that a try and if it works, I'll select this answer as correct.